# Angular and requirejs error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am trying to integrate angularjs with requirejs and I get this error in firebug console:  `myApp is not defined`  ===> `myApp is name of my module` .

Here's what I did in my project:
**main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'Scripts',
    paths: {
        'jQuery': '~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min',
        'angular': '~/Scripts/angular.min',
        'angularAnimate': '~/Scripts/angular-animate.min',
        'angularRoute': '~/Scripts/angular-ui-router.min',
        'mainCtrl': '~/App/Common/Script/mainCtrl',
        'myApp': '~/App/app',

    },

    shim: {
        angular: {
            deps: ['jQuery'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        angularRoute: {
            deps: ["angular", "angularRoute"],
            exports: 'angularRoute'
        },
        myApp: {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'myApp'
        },

    },


});


require(['angular', 'myApp', 'MainCtrl', 'angularRoute'], function (angular) {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

**app.js**

```
define([
    'angular',
    'angularRoute',
    'ngAnimate'
], function (angular) {


 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router']);

    myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        "some rout stuff"

});
```

**Factory.js**

```
require([
    "app",
    "toaster"
], function (app) {

myApp.factory('newBranchRequestFactory', ['$http', 'toaster', function ($http, toaster) {

 "blah"
  "blah" "blah"

]);
```

I'm getting error from **`factory.js`**  :   `require is not defined` ?

Comment: If you define a `baseUrl` you must define your paths according to it. And I don't think you need to set paths for your own app components, requireJS will handle that for you. Have a look at my [starter app strucure](https://github.com/glepretre/angular-requirejs-ready), it's a simple but full working example.

Comment: thx, i'll check that

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you return the myApp in app.js.